Keep image with bulleted list item (no page break)
I have a document with many numbered lists in it: each step has text using a Numbered List Item style. and an image using the Normal style. I want to make sure there's no page break in between. I've tried every combination of "Keep Text Together" and "Prevent Widows/Orphans" (I'm pretty sure) but it's not working. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated (hopefully ones using the styles menu so I don't have to manually adjust a million images).

This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

@macropod It seemed pretty similar to all the other questions with this tag...

Macropod is trying to help you. Stackoverflow is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is off-topic here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the Microsoft Community https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on Super User https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. (Hint: keep with next)
